# Inserting divisions in a flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this flexslider that i customized to this:
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t3sgbq5w/

Update: this is what i was able to do until now, but i'm not being able to manipulate the width so i'd have two parallel horizontal lines with 5 images on each line--> JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/wyebbuLj/

And now i'm trying to replace each image of the 3 images in the slider by a divider. to get this shape:

[image]

However i keep on facing problems in displaying the two horizontal lines of the divider (each 5 images).

Divider code:
HTML:

```
<div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>
       <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The images in your desired effect aren't 350x150 like they say, or do you want them to be?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @MCMastery no not like the placeholders, i'm trying to get them to the same height and width in the image above

Comment: @JamesKing i have a slider that has 3 images, that i'm trying to replace by 3 divisions (the code above) to take the form of the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi man here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5qropc0/

Row numbers can variate.

Added this wrraper in your li elements:

```
.mosaic {
    height: 300px !important;
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

script:

```
var row_Number = 2;
var wSpaceing = 4; //10% precentX space
var hSpace = 2 //10% percent Y space

 $(".slides li .mosaic").each(function () {
            var img_kiddos = $(this).children("img");

            if (img_kiddos.length > 1 && img_kiddos.length >= row_Number) {

                kiddoW = $(this).width();

                kiddoWSpace = 0;
                kiddoH = $(this).height();

                kiddwHSpace = 0;
                if (img_kiddos.length >= row_Number) {
                    kiddoWSpace = $(this).width() * wSpaceing / 100 / (Math.ceil(img_kiddos.length / row_Number) - 1);

                    kiddoW = ($(this).width() - kiddoWSpace * (Math.ceil(img_kiddos.length / row_Number) - 1)) / Math.ceil(img_kiddos.length / row_Number);
                }
                if (row_Number > 1) {
                    kiddwHSpace = $(this).height() * hSpace / 100 / (row_Number - 1);

                    kiddoH = ($(this).height() - kiddwHSpace * (row_Number - 1)) / row_Number;
                }

                var idx = 0;

                img_kiddos.each(function () {

                    $(this).width(kiddoW);
                    $(this).css("float", "left");

                    if (idx != 0 && idx % Math.ceil(img_kiddos.length /row_Number) !=  0)
                    {
                        $(this).css("margin-left", kiddoWSpace + "px");    
                    }
                    $(this).height(kiddoH);
                    if (idx  >= Math.ceil(img_kiddos.length /row_Number))
                    {
                         $(this).css("margin-top", kiddwHSpace + "px"); 
                    }
                idx++;
                })
            }
        });
```

Comment: tremor but the divider is now connected with the following slide,,Cannot be seperate?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, you want a gallery with all images showed in 2x5 format, when clicked, the slider with 10 images (one per slide) kicks in, or you want a slider with 3 slides having each 10 images 2X5 per slide?

Comment: Tremor when you switch between a slide and another the slides seems as one. What you did is what i want, but the problem is that the 3 slides in the jsfiddle look connected.